# How can I update an options list for a select element using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a select element that looks like this:

```
<select id="productId">

</select>
```

My current jquery is below:

```
...
if (data.success) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data.products, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<options id="' + val + '">' + key + '</option>');
    });
    var options = items.join('');
    $("#productId").html(options);
    //$("#productId").val(options);
    //$("#productId").append(options);
}
```

None of my attempts will update the select tag with my new options.  What am I missing?

Comment: You are using ```<options>``` instead of ```<option>```.

Comment: console.log(options) before passing it to $('#productId").html(). Make sure it's what you are expecting. Also, console.log($('#productId").length) to make sure you are finding the #productId element (is this code not in document.ready()?).

Comment: @alessandro1997 wow...that was it! I didn't see any errors in my console and I've been struggling with this for almost an hour now.  Thanks so much! Can't believe I didn't see that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
if (data.success) {
    $.each(data.products, function(key, val) {
        $('#productId').append('<option id="' + val + '">' + key + '</option>');
    });
}
```